# What non-Linux unixes support openat()?

Tags: unix, posix, portability

[openat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat) was added to POSIX in the POSIX.1-2008 revision, and has been supported by Linux since 2.6.16. How is support on non-Linux UNIXes? eg, Darwin, the *BSDs, and proprietary UNIXes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dragonfly BSD](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=openat&section=ANY) supports it, the rest of the BSDs don't. [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1463/openat-2.html#scrolltoc) of course does.

Comment: FreeBSD 8 also supports openat().

Answer (score 14):

Unlike the top answer is saying, all major BSDs and Apple's OS X seem to support it as of today:

- [DragonFly](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=openat&section=2) since DragonFly 2.3.
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=openat&sektion=2) since FreeBSD 8.0.
- [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat) since Linux 2.6.16 (for completeness).
- [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?openat+2+NetBSD-current) since NetBSD 7.0.
- [OpenBSD](http://www.manualpages.de/OpenBSD/OpenBSD-5.0/man2/openat.2.html) since OpenBSD 5.0.
- [OS X](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/openat/) since OS X 10.10.
- [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1463/open-2.html).

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD supports it since version 8.0