# Is there a Windows equivalent of `openat`?

Tags: winapi

The title pretty much says it, on Windows, can I somehow simulate multiple working directories in a multithreaded application by using something similar to `openat`?

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1670135/870079).

Comment: Can't you just concatenate your relative path to a desired directory? Like: FILE* f = fopen("D:\\Temp\\folder2\\folder3\\..\\foo.h", "r");

Comment: [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx): *"Each process has a **single** current directory [...]"* Simulating multiple current working directories is not possible. But then, I don't see how that is helpful in implementing an `openat` equivalent, anyway. Could you update your question to be specific about what you really want?

Comment: It's trivial to write your own function to behave this way.

Comment: @VladFeinstein This works up to the maximum path length.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See above, this isn't possible because you can run into maximum path length issues.

Comment: Well, use the Unicode API the long path prefix, as documented. I know that my programs are not bound by an artificial path length.

Comment: @IInspectable Saying that simulating multiple current working directories is not possible is a pretty strong statement – and your link just says that it's not possible to have multiple working directories for the operating system – but then that's not supported on Linux either and you can simulate multiple working directories by getting a file descriptor to them and using `openat`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That just moves the maximum path limit to 32K or so. A function similar to `openat` would remove that restriction.

Comment: No it would not. That's a hard limit. No way of escaping that one. Anyway, these comments aren't much fun because you seem to know more than we do, at least the way you are writing. In which case, I wish you all the best. You don't appear to need my help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry for my tone then. Will check if that's a hard limit, but I was under the impression that paths longer than that can be created.

Comment: The answer is right in front of you, in the first comment to the question. Nothing more needs to be said.

Comment: The documented feature of `openat` to simulate multiple working directories is ludicrous. It doesn't. It merely allows for a convoluted approach to have several **base directories**, implemented using the I/O API, instead of making that a simple string operation.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, maybe I don't understand what `openat` is supposed to do, but it seems to be pretty important as so many Unixes support it and it's even specified in some POSIX.

Comment: `openat` opens a file relative to another path. And since Unix is Unix, and Everything Is A File™ is the driving motivation (whether applicable or not), that other path is specified as a file descriptor (instead of a string). The natural way to solve the problem that `openat` tries to solve, is a string concatenation (possibly followed by a call to canonicalize the resulting pathname). That would feel too natural, though, and not at all Unix-like.

Comment: If you want to closely replicate the original `openat` call on Windows, you'll need to use [_get_osfhandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx) to get a native file handle from a file descriptor, and [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx) to retrieve the pathname. Concatenate the filename and open the file.

Comment: One of the important features is that your directory can be moved while open. And this is also a well known security problem. If your program is doing path concatenation but the sub path has been moved you could end up with file in very different places. If you think about it the current situation becomes insane, should never had implemented the way it is now.

Comment: And as usual given the problems it is windows who does it right and not unix. Windows locks the file path and all components down to root to avoid this modifications while on Unix you are fucked.

Comment: @Lothar Locking things like that on distributed file systems is *highly* unreliable.  Might explain a lot regarding who's *really* getting fucked...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is, and it's called `NtCreateFile()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380(v=vs.85).aspx) :)

`openat()` takes an open fd to a base directory from which path operations start. Similarly, you can supply a HANDLE to the ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory of `NtCreateFile()` to have whatever that directory's path is to be used as a base for relative path operations.

If going direct to the NT kernel API is too much for you and you want to remain within Win32, you can retrieve the current path of the base directory HANDLE easily enough (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx). If you open the directory without FILE_SHARE_DELETE permissions, nobody will be able to rename it and therefore the path retrieved will never move so long as you keep the HANDLE open.

You then stitch together the retrieved path with the relative path using normal string concatenation.

The NT kernel API approach is the only solution on Windows which allows the base directory HANDLE to be arbitrarily renamed by third party processes and that not cause races in your code. i.e. it's the only equivalent to POSIX `openat()`. I agree it's very unfortunate that Win32 doesn't make available this facility - in fact, Win32 doesn't make available atomic renames which is a very useful POSIX facility indeed to let you avoid lock files and is something the NT kernel API provides too.

Comment: The NT kernel provides lots of stuff for the sake of its historical POSIX subsystem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem

Comment: Maybe it does, but without proper documentation and example codes who is going to use it. I still had no time to figure out NtCreateFile and that after 8 years where i could use it for good but still blocking other processes file actions. But MS can't even document shit on their brand new WinUI 3/Windows App SDK.