# Nt HANDLE to Win32 handle

Tags: winapi, handle

POSIX 2008 offers a family of functions with *at() prefix, like `openat()`, which operates on files relatively the given directory descriptor. These functions seem practical in multi-threading environment, since they avoid potential races if some thread called `chdir()` or `fchdir()`. As I see the same goal can be achieved using Nt API like `NtCreateFile()`, if `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` structure has `RootDirectory` member set. What I'd like to do is to `NtCreateFile()` Nt handle and convert it to Win32 handle since a lot of my API depends on Win32 handles (e.g. as I understand `ReadFile()` can work only on Win32 handles). Is it possible? Or shall I rewrite the entire API to use Nt functions (e.g. `NtReadFile()`, `NtWriteFile()` and so on)?

Comment: Simply join the base path to the relative file name and pass an absolute file name.

Comment: `openat` has the most unintuitive semantics, and is best avoided. Likewise, basing file operations on the state of the current directory will turn into a bug, sooner or later. Using fully qualified pathnames is your best option: It's intuitive, readable, and debuggable.

Comment: There are some corner cases where full paths should be better avoided. As for building full path from relative (e.g. based on `GetCurrentDirectory()` call), it is error-prone and even dangerous in MT-environment. I also tend to think that the kernel itself has no notion of path represented as string, and it seems to be a wise choice.

Comment: There's no danger in passing a full path as a string. You are getting very confused. If there's a danger in doing so, then the exact same danger would apply to opening a handle to the base directory. Clearly there's a race if you ask for the process working directory repeatedly. Simply reducing the number of times you ask for the process working directory doesn't make that race go away. Tackle the real problem, which is your reliance on the process working directory when it is subject to change beyond your control.

Comment: There is no need to ever build a fully qualified pathname from the current working directory. The kernel very well knows how to interpret pathnames, not just to file objects, but all objects in the kernel namespace are based on strings.

Comment: I seem to recall that we did all this recently. Ah yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138524/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-openat

Comment: @ghostmansd forget `GetCurrentDirectory`. Just use fully qualified pathnames all the time, then the current directory can be ignored.